# alternative of getTaskFormKey method in activiti 7.0.0.SR1

Tags: activiti

Previously we have used activiti-5.15.1 version and we have formService.java class so following code work in it.

```
FormService fs = ServiceFactory.getFormService();

fs.getTaskFormKey(task.getProcessDefinitionId(), task.getTaskDefinitionKey());
```

Now we are upgrade activiti-7.0.0.SR1. But there is no FormService.java class.

we have tried ProcessDefinition class and used getFormKey() method but its not working in it.

We are looking for get form key of task in activiti-7.0.0.SR1.
Please suggest way to achieved this.

Comment: `FormService` was removed in activiti-7. use activiti-6 if you are dependent on the service

Answer (score 1):

The formProperties is exist in BpmnModel, you can access this to get it;

want to help you:

```java
package com.goahead.demoactiviti7.controller.service;

import org.activiti.bpmn.model.BpmnModel;
import org.activiti.bpmn.model.FlowElement;
import org.activiti.bpmn.model.FormProperty;
import org.activiti.bpmn.model.UserTask;
import org.activiti.engine.RepositoryService;
import org.activiti.engine.TaskService;
import org.activiti.engine.task.Task;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class FormService {

    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryService repositoryService;

    public List<FormProperty> getFormPropertiesFromBpmn(String  processDefinitionId,String taskId) {
        BpmnModel bpmnModel = repositoryService.getBpmnModel(processDefinitionId);
        Collection<FlowElement> flowElementCollection = bpmnModel.getMainProcess().getFlowElements();
        Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskId(taskId).singleResult();
        if (task == null) {
            System.out.println("taskid XXX is not existed.");
            return null;
        }
        String taskDefinitionKey = task.getTaskDefinitionKey();
        for (FlowElement flowElement: flowElementCollection) {
            if ("UserTask".equals(flowElement.getClass().getSimpleName()) && taskDefinitionKey.equals(flowElement.getId())) {
                return ((UserTask)flowElement).getFormProperties();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the call to your own package required? Please be explicit in your affiliation when recommending solutions that you're affiliated with.

Comment: it is just a utility class; The package name is mine, you can ignore it. Other import packages comes from spring and activiti7.  Just for reference.   :)